# jQuery AJAX status "200 OK", but no data response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, firefox

**jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
url : url,
type : 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
    'FN'    : 'GetPages',
    'PIN'   : '7659' 
},
xhrFields: {
   withCredentials: true
},
crossDomain: true,
success: function(data) {
    alert('succsess');
    console.log('data', data);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert('error');
    console.log(xhr.status);
    console.log(thrownError);
}
});
```

**Firebug Firefox Network**

[image: Firebug Error]

**What happens**

The AJAX "error:" event gets triggered and my *console.log* outputs are:

> xhr.status  -> 0
>
> thrownError -> (empty String)

**Is this normal? When I type the URL in a browser I receive a file download with the JSON content in it, this shouldn't be a problem right?**

Comment: Over a browser url the response is:
[{"pg":0,"descr":"PC1"},{"pg":1,"descr":"PC2"},{"pg":2,"descr":"PC3"},{"pg":3,"descr":"HG1"},{"pg":4,"descr":"HG2"},{"pg":5,"descr":"HG3"},{"pg":6,"descr":"HG4"},{"pg":7,"descr":"DW1"},{"pg":8,"descr":"DW2"},{"pg":9,"descr":"CMN"}]

Comment: Also my understanding is that **jsonp** won't work caus I am not permitted to change anything on the server and its response will stay in json format and not jsonp format

Comment: jsonp wont affect the server.  But it can help to get around CORS issues.  It may be your only option without modifying the server

Comment: @CrimsonChin ill have a look at that thanks!

Comment: @CrimsonChin only thing i managed to achieve was: 501 OPTIONS not implemented..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Thanks to @CrimsonChin I know its a Same Origin Policy problem**

> In computing, the same origin policy is an important security concept
>   for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as
>   JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating
>   from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with
>   no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and
>   properties across pages on different sites.[1]

(from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Granting JavaScript clients basic access to your resources simply requires adding one HTTP response header, namely:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example.com
```

(from http://enable-cors.org/)

Ofc, turning the JSON response into a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) response would also work. Thx @djakapm

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
$.ajax({ type : "GET", 
             url : URL, 
             data: {
             'FN'    : 'GetPages',
             'PIN'   : '7659' 
             },
            xhrFields: {
             withCredentials: true
             },
             crossDomain: true,
             dataType : "jsonp", 
             jsonp : "jsoncallback", 
             jsonpCallback : "SMS", 
             cache : true, 
              success : function(service_data) { 


                      },
              error : function(msg) {
                 alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
                }
          });
```

Comment: I runned this code and got following alert box:
{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}

And in firebug console an error:
SyntaxError: illegal character
in the **json** response

"descr":"CMN"}]� <-- and a arrow pointing at that Questionmark that shouldnt be there!?

Comment: @user1841515 try running the service_data through json lint (http://jsonlint.com/) to make sure the json is well formatted

Comment: @CrimsonChin I copied the json and run a check -> Valid JSON

Comment: @CrimsonChin The response isnt valid jsonp

Comment: Is this normal? When i type the url in a Browser i receive a file download with the json content in it, this shouldnt be a problem right?

Answer (score 2):

I cant figured out from the image, but if you are trying send AJAX request to different domain, you need to use **JSONP**, simple AJAX request will not be sufficient

Try to change `dataType: 'json'` to `dataType: 'jsonp'`

and add `callback=?` to your `URL`

Comment: Ok so i tried it out and i received following error:
 
Syntax Error
descr":"DW1"},{"pg":8,"descr":"DW2"},{"pg":9,"descr":"CMN"}]

Comment: And Error: jQuery172046435253250156217_1353659110552 was not called

Comment: Do you have the control over the server response? in php I usually give response like this: $_GET['callback'].'()'. it will mimic a javascript function call

Comment: @ djakapm No im afraid not.
But why do i get a response when i type it in url of browser?

Comment: @user1841515 you dont violate CORS rules by accessing the url directly.  I honestly think you're only option is to update the servers web.config to allow CORS